# OpenAPI does not validate String array query param values

Tags: java, jersey, openapi, openapi-generator

An endpoint changed from accepting a single id parameter

```
- name: id
  in: query
  schema:
    $ref: "#/components/schemas/id"
```

to accepting an array:

```
- name: id
  in: query
  schema:
    type: array
    items: 
      $ref: "#/components/schemas/id"
```

with id defined as:

```
id:
  type: string
  pattern: "^[1-9][0-9]{0,9}$"
  description: Identifies a Location within the EDDI API (has no wider interpretation).
  example: "1"
```

but it seems, pattern validation was lost along the way. After reading contents of https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/4947, I tried to implement it this way:

```
    - name: id
      in: query
      schema:
        type: array
        items:
          type: object
          properties:
            item:
              $ref: "#/components/schemas/id"
```

And the generated Id object even has the `@Pattern(regexp="^[1-9][0-9]{0,9}$")` on getter and `@Valid` on it's only field: `private @Valid String item;`, but validation seem not to be invoked by Jersey: constraints list is empty in org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl#validateMetaConstraints. Looks like in order to have the object validated I need to make OpenApiGenerator to put @Valid constraint on the query parameter in the auto-generated interface...

Is there a way to enforce validation defined in OpenApi spec on Jersey/Jetty without writing the code to validate parameters on the backend manually?

P.S. As it is written in the bug (the link above), defining array items as string won't produce @Valid ad @Pattern annotations

```
    - name: id
      in: query
      schema:
        type: array
        items:
          type: string
          properties:
            item:
              $ref: "#/components/schemas/id"
```

P.P.S OpenApiGenerator version: 4.3.1,  Jersey version=2.29.1,  Jetty version=9.4.6.v20170531